# what could be the possible reasons of MQTT connection close unexpectedly in iOS?

Tags: ios, mqtt

My iOS application sometime doesn't connect  with MQTT Server and i'm getting following log :

"**Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=60 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation timed out**"

It happens randomly with different network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had same problem with one of my iOS application which is using MQTT as presence service. In our case it was the firewall of network which is blocking MQTT default port (**1833**).

We solved it in [Applozic chat SDK](https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-iOS-SDK)  by redirecting to different port like **8080** (This port is mostly opened under enterprise firewalls).

Hope this will help you finding your issue :).